# Modis Reprojection tool, BAD or missing Total_BANDS values

Tags: coordinate-system, modis, modis-reprojection-tool

I am trying to convert Modis terra Level 2 data 3KM swath i.e "MOD04_3K" from HDF to GeoTiff. I am using Modis Swath tool. When I input my file it gives an error saying "BAD or missing Total_BANDS values". When I input the file for Level 2 data 10 km swath it does not give any error. 
Questions:

1. What is the problem with 3 KM swath data i.e giving "BAD or missing Total_BANDS values error"
2. When I try to Run tool for 10 Km swath it asks for Geolocation file. I have no idea about Geolocation file. It does not come with the downloaded MODIS file.

Or if u can suggest any other tool for reprojection of MODIS data and the conversion from HFD to GeoTiff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug, MRTSwath has problems with V006 collection, I don't know why (MRTSwath last version is from 2010, it's too old). Try with [HEG](http://newsroom.gsfc.nasa.gov/sdptoolkit/HEG/HEGDownload.html).

For geolocation file, go to [Level-1 and Atmosphere Archive & Distribution System](https://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/search/index.html). You'll find `MOD03 Geolocation 1 km` file.